# Creating package version results in XYZ not available in this organization

Tags: managed-package, second-generation-packaging, sfdx-error

In trying ot create a 2nd-generation managed package, I created a scratch org, added a custom meta data type, and tried to run the following to create a package version using the following:

```
sf package version create --package "MyPackagName" --installation-key myKeyHere --wait 10 -v devHubOrgEmail@example.com --verbose
```

The DevHub org is my production org.

I get the following response:

```
Error (1): Multiple errors occurred: 
(1) TestCredential.Main_Credential: Custom metadata type TestCredential__mdt is not available in this organization.
```

I have no idea how to solve this. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This could be simply because you might not have pulled the custom metadata type and the records to your local project folder.

2GP packaging is based on the metadata types in your source folder and not on the org. Make sure your project source folder has all the necessary files and dependencies.

Comment: I went in the org explorer and pulled it down locally. Anything else it could be?

Comment: Did you also pull the custom metadata records?

Comment: Yes I pulled down the 1 metadata record as well -- same result though.

Comment: Can you please share your folder structure screen shot so we confirm what you missing?